# How many generations apart can a DNA test for blood relations be valid?

Tags: genetics, dna, human-genetics

Suppose an American suspects he is a descendant of George Washington and he has a strand of hair of George Washington. Can a DNA test be done to prove that he is indeed a true descendant of the great Founding Father?

How many generations apart can a DNA test for ancestry still be valid?

Comment: What research have you done to answer this (interesting) question yourself? You might be interested in the question of Thomas Jefferson's offspring.

Comment: i would like to ask: " how many generations of parents can be found from all current people's dna? if all dna of all all current people is got, how many years of past parentship relations can be found from it? " but it is too short. would you like to edit your question that way?